# Replace a hexadecimal value by a (modified) decimal value in a text file

Tags: bash, text-processing

Inside a file `test.txt` I have a hexadecimal value

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000047546124890225541102135415377465907
```

*Only one line*. There are no other lines or characters. It is also identified only by 0x.

I want to convert this hex value to decimal (`388355321549592156970965297418600041568519`), subtract 1, and overwrite the original value with the result of this operation in `test.txt`

Ultimately, the data in the `test.txt` file should be converted from

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000047546124890225541102135415377465907
```

to

```
388355321549592156970965297418600041568518
```

I would be very grateful if you could tell me how to do it with Bash (Linux shell).

Comment: Statistically unusual for a hex value with 35 digits to have no digits in the range A-F -- a random distribution would expect 13 such digits. It's not much of a test case. Assuming  you can isolate each hex string (without the `0x`), the standard command `dc` is your friend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `perl`, editing the file in-place:

```
perl -Mbigint -lpi -e '$_ = hex($_) - 1' your-file
```

That assumes the whole line is the hex number. To convert all hex numbers, wherever they're found:

```
perl -Mbigint -lpi -e 's{\b0x[\da-f]+\b}{hex($&) - 1}gie' your-file
```

Answer (score 6):

GNU `awk`

```
gawk -M '{print strtonum($0)-1}' file
```

`-M` (or `--bignum`) is for arbitrary precision arithmetic. `strtonum($0)` takes the numeric value of the record, treating the string as a hexadecimal number because it starts with `0x`. Use `-i inplace` for in-place editing of the input file.

Comment: Note that you need gawk 4.1.0 or newer and bignum support to be enabled at build time.

Answer (score 4):

By one command in bash with here string and calculator (with postfix notation):

```
dc -e '16iAo?1-p' <<<$(<file) >file
```

`16i` - *input radix*
`Ao` - *output radix*
`?` - *reads a line*
`1-` - *subtract one*
`p` - *prints*

Attention:
Not specified in your example. `dc` calculator accepts hex digits [ABCDEF] in uppercase way.

Answer (score 3):

Bash has an arithmetic expansion `$(( ... ))` which can deal with hex directly, so

```bsh
decrement_file () {
   number=$(( $(cat $1) - 1 ))
   echo $number > $1
}
```

would give you a function that can deal with your file:

```bsh
decrement_file test.txt
```

Of course you can also just manually do these two steps on the command line, but it felt like something that made sense to put in a function. Add that function definition in your `~/.bashrc`, and you can call it anytime.

Small problem: your numbers are too large for bash's arithmetic to directly deal with. So, you need to rely on external tools (or write a bigint library in shell script ... err, no). Philippos' answer depends on `bc`, I'll say that's probably less likely to be installed on your machine anyways than python, so, I'd probably just write a python script instead:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
value = -1
with open(sys.argv[1], "r", encoding="ascii") as file:
  value += int(file.read())
with open(sys.argv[1], "w", encoding="ascii") as file:
  file.write(str(value))
```

and save it as "decrement_file" somewhere in your path, `chmod a+x decrement_file` to make it executable, and then use it `decrement_file test.txt`.

A really minimal, one-off solution to all this would be

```bsh
VAL=$(python3 -c "print( int($(cat test.txt)) - 1)"); echo $VAL > test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

**This answer was given while the question asked about a hex number somewhere in a file. Later, the question was updated that the whole file consists of just that number. This answer still works, but of course you would not use `sed` in this special case. I still leave it here as a reference for someone seeking for an answer to the original problem. Please also note the comments.**

If you have a `bash`, you probably also have GNU `sed` (with the `e` flag to the `s` command). Then you also need he `bc` calculator, because your number is too big for `bash`:

```
sed 's/^0x0*\(.*\)/echo "ibase=16; \1-1"|bc/e' yourfile
```

- I assume, that each line starting with `0x` should be converted, but you can easily adapt that
- `0x0*\(.*\)` is the pattern to change. We remove the leading `0x` and superfluous leading zeroes, while everything else is in the `\(…\)`, so it can be referred to as `\1` in the replacement
- `echo "ibase=16; \1-1"|bc` is the shell command to be `e`xecuted by the shell after replacement
- The actual calculation is `\1-1`, which is the cleaned hex number minus one. The `ibase=16` tells `bc` that this is a hex number

Comment: Note that, in bases above 10, digits representing parts of numbers such as A-F must be in uppercase. Lower-case letters represent variables and will throw syntax errors in `bc`. So hex values need to be passed through `tr 'a-f' 'A-F'` first (but the bc commands like `ibase` must not).

Comment: Would be worth noting that if the input file cannot be totally trusted to contain just that hex number, that amounts to an arbitrary command evaluation vulnerability. I'd change the pattern to `^0x0*\([0123456789ABCDEF]\{1,\}\)$` to mitigate that risk.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  I missed that point completely. `man dc` gives a command: "**!** ::  Will run the rest of the line as a system command."

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, GNU `sed`'s `e` command runs a shell, so you get a vulnerability regardless of that command you use. IMO, that `e` should really be avoided. It should not have been added to GNU `sed` in the first place as that makes the whole of `sed` a lot more dangerous.